# Web Site track visitor but no cookies

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi We don't use cookies ourselves on our website except for links to Google maps and a contact form. I have been told we need a cookie disclaimer banner. Our visitors seem to land on various pages and what I don't want is for the banner to appear on every other page they may browse through. Is it possible to "hold" the ip address ONLY during their visit and erase it when their session is completed. I don't want to start using cookies. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `We don't use cookies ourselves on our website except for ...` so, you do in fact use cookies - or use `localStorage`

Comment: @Jaromanda X. Thank you for your comment. I totally agree which is why I used the word "except"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, it's possible to implement a solution that holds the IP address only for the duration of a visitor's session without using persistent cookies. Instead of relying on cookies, you can use server-side techniques to manage session data.

One approach is to store a session identifier in the server's memory, associated with the visitor's IP address. This session identifier is transmitted to the user's browser through the URL or as part of the form data. This way, the banner would only appear during their current session, and you won't be storing any information on the user's device.

Here's a simplified overview of the process:

1. **User Visit:**

   - When a user lands on your website, generate a unique session identifier on the server.
   - Associate this identifier with the user's IP address.
2. **Displaying the Banner:**

   - Include the session identifier in links to Google Maps and the contact form.
   - When the user navigates to pages with these links, the session identifier is sent back to the server.
3. **Banner Logic:**

   - Check the session identifier when processing requests.
   - If the session identifier is valid and matches the user's IP address, display the banner.
   - If the session has ended or the user's IP changes, the banner won't appear.
4. **Session Expiry:**

   - Set a reasonable session timeout to clear session data after a period of inactivity.

By implementing this server-side session management, you can achieve the goal of showing the banner only during a user's visit without relying on persistent cookies. It's important to consider user privacy and comply with relevant data protection regulations in your implementation.

Comment: of course, with the proliferation of CG-NAT an IP address could be "associated" with multiple disparate people (albeit all with the same internet provider) - though, I've just re-read the answer, and that may not be as much an issue as I thought

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You've rightly highlighted the consideration of shared IPs due to CG-NAT. In the context of displaying a session-specific banner based on IP addresses, the impact of shared IPs within the same internet provider is minimized, as the goal is to enhance the user's experience during their session rather than uniquely identifying individual users.

Comment: @Atulk. Thank you for your detailed answer. I presume you are talking about PHP. Unfortunately I have not used this before - this is only a simple website for my local charity. I will consult with the Charity Trustees.

Comment: @Learning you tagged the question with php so it's reasonable for people to assume you're open to a php-based answer :-). And indeed a server-side solution is really the only feasible one in this case. Note that people might be annoyed that the cookie banner reappears for each new session when they visit your site, whereas other sites tend to make the banner disappear more permanently

Comment: @ADyson. Thank you for your comment. I put php as I thought it might involve that. That is a very good point about the banner reapperaing. annoying people. I think the way forward will be a "proper" disclaimer - I will have to see what is available

Comment: @Learning I suspect that people actually make the banner go away in most cases by adding a cookie :-). Or maybe localstorage would do the job as well

Comment: @ADyson, Appreciate your comment. Indeed, that's precisely why I chose this question.